# Parsekit not compiling cleanly

Tags: parsekit

I downloaded the latest version from google code, am using xcode 4.4 (with command line tools), 10.7.4 and am getting the error below. Any idea?

```
In file included from /Users/otusweb/SkyDrive/Projects/parsekit/test/PKTokenNode.m:16:
/Users/otusweb/SkyDrive/Projects/parsekit/include/ParseKit/PKToken.h:42:13: 
error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression
#if PLATFORM(TWITTER_STATE)
    ~~~~~~~~^
/Users/otusweb/SkyDrive/Projects/parsekit/include/ParseKit/PKToken.h:67:13: error: 
token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression
#if PLATFORM(TWITTER_STATE)
    ~~~~~~~~^
/Users/otusweb/SkyDrive/Projects/parsekit/include/ParseKit/PKToken.h:168:13: error: 
token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression
#if PLATFORM(TWITTER_STATE)
    ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downloaded the update that was made on google code to remove the platform preprocessor command and it now works...

Olivier